# Wait for loop to finish $.getJSON for each array item before outputting data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an array of names which I need to retrieve data from, and I'm currently doing this with $.getJSON inside a loop. It works and I can retrieve the data, but to output the correct value I need to use setTimeout or similar. I'm wondering if there's a more refined way of doing what I'm looking to achieve.

Here's what I've got.

```js
var names = ["riotgames", "example"];
var online = [];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + names[i], function(data) {
    if (data.stream != null) {
      online.push(data.stream.channel.display_name);
    };
  });
}

console.log(online) // outputs []

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(online) // outputs correctly
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The request is *asynchronous*.  You *cannot* access any of the data from outside the callback.  You are going to need to restructure your code to only handle the data in `online` inside the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing `$.getJSON`, you are triggering *asynchronous* requests.  This means they run in the background.  You do not *wait* for them to finish, their callbacks will trigger (like an event) once the request is done.

This means you *cannot* access `online` from *outside* the callback(s).

If you want to "wait" for *all* the requests to finish, then I suggest using promises.  You can use `$.when` to combine all the requests into one promise then run a callback once everything is done.

```
var names = ["riotgames", "example"];
var promises = [];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    // $.getJSON returns a promise
    promises.push($.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + names[i]));
}

// Combine all promises
// and run a callback
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){
    var online = [];

    // This callback will be passed the result of each AJAX call as a parameter
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        // arguments[i][0] is needed because each argument
        // is an array of 3 elements.
        // The data, the status, and the jqXHR object
        online.push(arguments[i][0].stream.channel.display_name);
    }

    console.log(online);
});
```